# DropDownList envia un null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tengo un formulario en donde hay un DropDownList para el campo Sede, el punto es que al momento de enviar me aparece el error **ORA-01400: no se puede realizar una inserción NULL en ("SENCSIGA"."TBL_CHARLA"."SEDE_CHARLA")**, los datos que cargue al DropDownList son fijos, no sé si eso afectará, pero el punto es que no captura el valor después de haber seleccionado un texto en el DropDownList.

**CharlasController**

```
public ActionResult CrearCharla()
    {
        List<ClsSede> listaSede = new List<ClsSede>();

        ClsSede Sede1 = new ClsSede();
        Sede1.sede_Text = "LIMA - SAN BORJA";
        Sede1.sede_Value = "LIMA - SAN BORJA";

        ClsSede Sede2 = new ClsSede();
        Sede2.sede_Text = "LIMA - LOS OLIVOS";
        Sede2.sede_Value = "LIMA - LOS OLIVOS";

        ClsSede Sede3 = new ClsSede();
        Sede3.sede_Text = "LIMA - CHORRILLOS";
        Sede3.sede_Value = "LIMA - CHORRILLOS";

        listaSede.Add(Sede1);
        listaSede.Add(Sede2);
        listaSede.Add(Sede3);

        ViewBag.Sedes = new SelectList(listaSede, "sede_Text", "sede_Value");

        return View(new ClsCharla());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CrearCharla(ClsCharla charla)
    {

        List<ClsSede> listaSede = new List<ClsSede>();

        ClsSede Sede1 = new ClsSede();
        Sede1.sede_Text = "LIMA - SAN BORJA";
        Sede1.sede_Value = "LIMA - SAN BORJA";

        ClsSede Sede2 = new ClsSede();
        Sede2.sede_Text = "LIMA - LOS OLIVOS";
        Sede2.sede_Value = "LIMA - LOS OLIVOS";

        ClsSede Sede3 = new ClsSede();
        Sede3.sede_Text = "LIMA - CHORRILLOS";
        Sede3.sede_Value = "LIMA - CHORRILLOS";

        listaSede.Add(Sede1);
        listaSede.Add(Sede2);
        listaSede.Add(Sede3);

        ViewBag.Sedes = new SelectList(listaSede, "sede_Text", "sede_Value", charla.sede_Charla);

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ViewBag.mensaje = "Datos Invalidos";
            return View(new ClsCharla());
        }

        ViewBag.mensaje = "Datos Validos";

        ClsConexion con = new ClsConexion();
        var Cnx = con.Conexion();

        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("SIMEXA_SP_REGISTRAR_CHARLA", Cnx);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("param_titulo", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = charla.titulo_Charla;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("param_descrip", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = charla.descrip_Charla;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("param_fecha", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = charla.fecha_Charla;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("param_hora", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = charla.hora_Charla;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("param_lugar", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = charla.lugar_Charla;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("param_sede", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = charla.sede_Charla;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("param_requisito", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = charla.requisito_Charla;
        Cnx.Open();

        //OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        OracleTransaction tx = Cnx.BeginTransaction();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        tx.Commit();

        Cnx.Close();
        cmd.Dispose();
        Cnx.Dispose();

        return View(charla);
    }
```

**Vista CrearCharla**

```
    @model wsCharlas.Models.ClsCharla

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CrearCharla";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>CrearCharla</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>ClsCharla</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">

            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID_Charla, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ID_Charla, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.titulo_Charla, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.titulo_Charla, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.titulo_Charla, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.descrip_Charla, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.descrip_Charla, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.descrip_Charla, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.fecha_Charla, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.fecha_Charla, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.fecha_Charla, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.hora_Charla, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.hora_Charla, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.hora_Charla, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.lugar_Charla, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.lugar_Charla, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.lugar_Charla, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.sede_Charla, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">

                @Html.DropDownList("sede_Text", (SelectList)ViewBag.Sedes, "Seleccione una Sede", new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.requisito_Charla, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.requisito_Charla, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.requisito_Charla, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

**Clase Charla**

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace wsCharlas.Models
{
    public class ClsCharla
    {
        public string ID_Charla { get; set; }
        public string titulo_Charla { get; set; }
        public string descrip_Charla { get; set; }
        public string fecha_Charla { get; set; }
        public string hora_Charla { get; set; }
        public string lugar_Charla { get; set; }
        public string sede_Charla { get; set; }
        public string requisito_Charla { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Clase Sede**

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace wsCharlas.Models
{
    public class ClsSede
    {
        public string sede_Text { get; set; }
        public string sede_Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si defines el `select` con el nombre `sede_Text`

```
@Html.DropDownList("sede_Text", (SelectList)ViewBag.Sedes, ...
```

sera con este mismo nombre que viajara al servidor en el `post` por lo tanto el `model binding` espera en la class del model una propiedad con ese mismo nombre para mapear

Pero en la class `ClsCharla` no defines ninguna propiedad con ese nombre.

Si quieres que mapee con la propiedad

```
public string sede_Charla { get; set; }
```

entonces deberias usar

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model=> model.sede_Charla, (SelectList)ViewBag.Sedes, ...
```

asi viajara con ese nombre que asignara en el model

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda :)

Comment: Y gracias por haberme hecho dar cuenta de la diferencia entre DropDownList y DropDownListFor